# How set requirements for text input field (html/php) ?

Tags: php, html, input, filtering

In my php script i have this input field.

```
   <input type="text" name="try" size="10" id="try" maxlength="5" >
```

What is the easy way to make i require 5 characters and show an error message if they are not only letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HTML5 you can use the [`pattern`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="try" size="10" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5}" title="5 alphabetic characters exactly">
```

This will allow exactly 5 characters, which can only be uppercase or lowercase alphabetic characters.

Comment: +1 on the supposition that you don't need cross-browser support. I believe this will not work on ie or safari -> [HTML5 input pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: True .. i just tested on FF

Comment: Yeah, I think if support is needed for IE and Safari, it will argue for a JavaScript validation.  Maybe some day they will get it together.  We can hope.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do that in jQuery on the client side.  You will also need to do it on the server side, since JavaScript can (and will) be bypassed by an attack vector.  A regular expression like this will do the server-side validation in PHP.

$rgx = '/[A-Z]{5,}/i';

Combining the approach...

http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_axxess.php?q=abcde
http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_axxess.php?q=ab
http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_axxess.php?q=abcdefg

```
<?php // RAY_temp_axxess.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// A REGEX FOR 5+ LETTERS
$rgx = '/^[A-Z]{5,}$/i';

if (isset($_GET['q']))
{
    if (preg_match($rgx, $_GET['q']))
    {
        echo 'GOOD INPUT OF 5+ LETTERS IN ';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "VALIDATION OF {$_GET['q']} FAILED FOR REGEX: $rgx";
    }
}

// CREATE THE FORM
$form = <<<ENDFORM
<form>
<input type="text" name="q" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}" title="At least 5 alphabetic characters" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
ENDFORM;
echo $form;
```

Comment: I tested this in FF and Chrome only.  Both had the expected browser response.  Of course if it's direct input, only the server test will get executed, so that's why you need both a belt and suspenders ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{5,}" required />
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

validate your form before view like this and use strlen to check the length of input:

```
if(isset($_POST['mySubmit'])) {
    if(strlen($_POST['try']) < 5) {
        $error = "Too short";
    }
    else {
        $valid = true;
        //Do whathever you need when form is valid
    }
}
else {
    if(isset($error)) {
        echo "<p>$error</p>";
    }

    //echo your form here
    echo "<form method='post' action='thisPhpScript.php'>
              <input type='text' name='try' size='10' id='try' maxlength='5' >
          </form>";
}
```

Haven't tested this so might have syntax errors.

Comment: and how dow i check if there are numbers or special characters ?

Comment: @Axxess i hightly suggest using HTML5 and PHP together

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the page submits to itself.

Quick and Dirty.

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['try']) & strlen($_POST['try']) != 5 & ctype_alpha( $_POST['try'] != true) {
$error['try'] = "This field must contains 5 characters and contain only a-z and A-Z";
// stop whatever you normally do if submitted.
}
?>
```

Later on the page where you show this field.

```
<?php if (isset($errors['try'])) { echo $errors['try']; } ?>
<input type="text" name="try" size="10" id="try" maxlength="5" >
```